# Elastic Beanstalk - Following services are not running web

Tags: github, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am sorry if I missed to put any vital information.

I have developed a flask application and want to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. I am trying to upload it from my github.

I have tried it multiple times but always run into the same issue. The environment always sets up with ok status but as soon as I try to connect it to the CodePipeline the status turns Degraded.

[image]

[image]

The link redirects to : [502 Bad Gateway](http://diabetes-env.eba-qdprmc58.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

[This](https://github.com/utsavnagda/Diabetes-Beanstalk-deployment) is the project that I am trying to deploy. If there is something missing in my code please let me know.

I tried to add some roles that were suggested online but nothing has worked so far. Also tried to change region but didn't work either.

If there are any simpler alternatives to deploy my personal projects I would love the suggestions, preferably free. (Also tried azure but ran into similar issues there as well)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does it show when you click "view causes" next to Degraded? Also check in logs tab to see the cause of the error.

Comment: @ArpitJain When I click on view cause it just redirects me to the health tab as shown in img 2. As for logs, I can only access them by downloading them. I went through them and didn't find anything that could be pointing to the error. Similar to this post: [Eb environment health issue](https://repost.aws/questions/QUrzUfoZcVQ4iiMUBXh_2-Bg/eb-environment-health-issue)

Comment: I couldn't solve the issue in Beanstalk but I found an alternative that works. Deployed my website on Render. Was able to host it with almost no problem.